# KSOAP2 implement crech

Tags: android, ksoap2

i am using the ksoap2 (ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) in my project,
everything work fine  but suddenly the  code stop working in every class that i implemented this(ksoap2)
interface i get an error, here is the LogCat result showing:

```
05-02 06:21:45.969: I/System.out(345): debugger has settled (1341)
05-02 06:21:46.234: I/dalvikvm(345): Failed resolving Lbikorot/Main/Entities/Users; interface 170 'Lorg/ksoap2/serialization/KvmSerializable;'
05-02 06:21:46.234: W/dalvikvm(345): Link of class 'Lbikorot/Main/Entities/Users;' failed
05-02 06:21:46.245: I/dalvikvm(345): Failed resolving Lbikorot/Main/Entities/Users; interface 170 'Lorg/ksoap2/serialization/KvmSerializable;'
05-02 06:21:46.245: W/dalvikvm(345): Link of class 'Lbikorot/Main/Entities/Users;' failed
05-02 06:21:46.245: W/dalvikvm(345): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 284
05-02 06:21:46.245: D/dalvikvm(345): VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x0017
05-02 06:21:46.245: D/dalvikvm(345): VFY: dead code 0x0019-001e in Lbikorot/Main/LogInActivity;.Login ()V
05-02 06:21:46.264: I/dalvikvm(345): Failed resolving Lbikorot/Main/Entities/Users; interface 170 'Lorg/ksoap2/serialization/KvmSerializable;'
05-02 06:21:46.264: W/dalvikvm(345): Link of class 'Lbikorot/Main/Entities/Users;' failed
05-02 06:21:46.264: E/dalvikvm(345): Could not find class 'bikorot.Main.Entities.Users', referenced from method global.utilities.GlobalUtil.<init>
05-02 06:21:46.264: W/dalvikvm(345): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 90 (Lbikorot/Main/Entities/Users;) in Lglobal/utilities/GlobalUtil;
05-02 06:21:46.264: D/dalvikvm(345): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0009
05-02 06:21:46.264: D/dalvikvm(345): VFY: dead code 0x000b-0048 in Lglobal/utilities/GlobalUtil;.<init> ()V
```

please help!!!!!!!

ok i am using HttpTransportSE (ksoap2 2.6.4), but the code still crashing when it hit a call that implamenting the ksoap interface, here is the code of one of this class:

```
    package bikorot.Main.Entities;

   import java.util.Hashtable;
   import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
   import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;

   public class Users implements KvmSerializable {

  public int kod;
  public String name;
  public String password;
  public int kod_users_group;
  public boolean pail;
  public String edu_Bikoret;


  public Users()
  { }

  public Users(int kod, String name, String password)
  {
      this.kod = kod;
      this.name = name;
      this.password = password;
  }

  @Override
public int getPropertyCount() {
    return 6;
}
  @Override
public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
        info.name = "kod";
        break;
    case 1:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "name";
        break;
    case 2:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "password";
        break;
    case 3:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
        info.name = "kod_users_group";
        break;
    case 4:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.BOOLEAN_CLASS;
        info.name = "pail";
        break;
    case 5:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "edu_Bikoret";
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

  @Override
public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        kod = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        break;
    case 1:
        name = value.toString();
        break;
    case 2:
        password = value.toString();
    case 3:
        kod_users_group = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        break;
    case 4:
        pail =Boolean.parseBoolean( value.toString());
    case 5:
        edu_Bikoret = value.toString();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

  @Override
public Object getProperty(int arg0) {

    switch (arg0) {
    case 0:
        return kod;
    case 1:
        return name;
    case 2:
        return password;
    case 3:
        return kod_users_group;
    case 4:
        return pail;
    case 5:
        return edu_Bikoret;
    }

    return null;
        }

     }
```

Comment: Hi , I dnt knw abt your error but using pretty old Jar file .Can u please add ur error in format form , it too difficult to read like this.

Comment: hi Mohit, ok i replaced the old jar with a new one (2.6.4) i getting an error androidHttpTransport cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: try compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the getters and setters to the `Users` class.